# How can i Disable session files creation on Code Igniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a folder on ci4 of sessions which doesnt stop do grow. I need to disable its creation. The documentation doesnt say anything about it (https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html).

I have tried to put some variables on .env files but didnt work.

```
app.sessionDriver = 'CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\FileHandler'
app.sessionCookieName = 'sessao'
app.sessionExpiration = 0
app.sessionSavePath = NULL
app.sessionMatchIP = FALSE
app.sessionTimeToUpdate = 0
app.sessionRegenerateDestroy = true
```

It says that the garbage colletor will delete it in future but it doesnt.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The session will be destroyed when it has expired. In your setting, you have no expiration for your session:

> `app.sessionExpiration = 0`

Since the session never expires  it never gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem with CI session files, it was dozens of GB in size. As I used *JWT(JSON Web Token)*, I didn't need the session feature in CodeIgniter itself, but tons of session files made my API very slow.

My final solution is as following:

I disabled line 912 in **/system/Session/Session.php**, and it resolved my trouble.

```
protected function startSession()
{
    if (ENVIRONMENT === 'testing') {
        $_SESSION = [];

        return;
    }

    session_start(); // @codeCoverageIgnore // disable this line :)
}
```

After that, I could see `index.html` only under `/writable/session/` directory.